# Read Excel file that contains Tab Characters into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have excel files that have tab characters and newlines in the Description column.

I am loading the files into Pandas data frames.

My goal is to replace all sequences of special characters with a single semicolon and space, then write the data out again as CSV files.

The generated CSV files are garbled wherever there were tabs. I am not sure where the problem began, but I suspect it is in the loading of the Excel file, not the writing of the CSV file, because the results show that the newlines and tabs have been replaced.

I am hoping that the `read_excel` function has parameters that might fix this issue.

Here is the code that loads the files:

```py
import sys
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Extract data from Excel files and merge them into a single Pandas Dataframe.
def extract(input_files, sheet_name):
    # Excel files in the path
    file_list = glob.glob(input_files + "/*.xls*")

    print(f'Number of files to load: {len(file_list)}')
    
    # list of data frames read from excel files we want to merge.
    excl_list = []
 
    for file in file_list:
        excl_list.append(pd.read_excel(io=file, sheet_name=sheet_name, header=0))
 
    # create a new dataframe to store the
    # merged data file.
    excl_merged = pd.concat(excl_list, axis=0)

    print('Files merged')
    
    return excl_merged
```

Here is the code that transforms the Description columns to replace the offending characters:

```py
def transform(df, confidence, min_length, operations):
    if "special" in operations.lower():
        df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.replace(r'[\v\n\r\t]+','; ', regex=True)

    # ... Omitted code ...

    return df
```

Comment: CSV files can handle embedded tabs and newlines.  That's what quotes are for.

Comment: I know that CSV files CAN handle them, but only if they are properly quoted. Something in my pipeline causes single records to be split into multiple records and the columns go all crazy.

Comment: I hear you, but wouldn't it be better to find the element that's doing that, and fix i t?

Comment: Hi, are you dealing with files of different kind (.xls, .xlsx, etc.)? What happens if you use `engine="openpyxl"` in pd.read_excel?